# Delete comments or annotations from web files by 'tr' or 'sed' command

Tags: linux, sed, tr

I'm willing to compress HTML files by Linux command like this.

```
tr -d "\n\t\r"
```

But how can I delete comments or annotations from web files.

For example,

```
<! -- adcdefg -->

<% -- asdfasdf -- %>

/* asdfasdfasdf */
```

I just wanna eliminate such comments.

Comment: use sed with s option

Comment: Consider a third party tool. https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

Comment: `tr` is not going to be the right tool for comment removal (though it is fine for removing newlines etc — or replacing them with spaces which might be safer).

Answer (score 0):

try (but be carreful it could easily remove too much so backup your files first)

for `<! -- adcdefg -- >` and `<% -- asdfasdf -- % >` (no space after the `<`)

```
sed 's/<[!%][^>]*>//g' YourFile
```

**Explaination**

pattern `<[!%][^>]*>`

- start by `<`
- followed by `!` or `%` (using the class `[!%]`)
- followed by any non `>` char  (class starting by `^` mean "not one of them", `*`mean any occurence, including 0) so `[^>]*` is any occurence of non `>`
- followed by `>`

action `s/Pattern//g`

- replace Pattern by nothing (the `//` is replace pattern with nothing inside so it remove the search pattern)
- `g` option is used to specify all occurence on the line, not only the first (by default)

for `/* blabla */` it a bit hot because it could include lot of stuff inside and on several lines. You should give some assumption to avoid a huge unreadeble sed ;-)

in both case any string that contain the end delimiter will cause problem with such a basic sed

Comment: oops missing a `*` after `[^>]`

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Do you know any reference about this way. I don't understand this part '<[!%][^>]*>'

Comment: added comment in post